# Qt store separator action

Tags: c++, qt

I need to save some menu structure in some container (e.g. `std::vector<QAction*>`). How can I store a separator in a container like this?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `QAction::setSeparator` and `isSeparator`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes :)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think this is a nice question, why don't you publish the answer so it can be accepted and other Qt developers are able to use it?